# Total columns across a row and add that total to the number of rows found in another table with one query

Tags: mysql

I've got `table A` and `table B`.

`table A` has three columns: `id`, `data1`, `data2`.

`table B` has two columns: `post_id`, `comment_id`. `post_id` contains a list of `id`s from `table A`.

I wish to add `data1` and `data2` together and then add that result to the number of rows in `table B` containing the `post_id`.

How do I achieve this with a single query?

**UPDATE** Here is some pseudocode which doesn't work, but which should make it clear what I'm trying to achieve:

`select a.id, (a.data1 + data2 + count(b.post_id)) as total from a INNER JOIN b on a.id = b.post_id having total > 0;`

Comment: "`post_id` contains a list of `id`" what do you mean by this? there is not list in mysql

Answer (score 0):

Push the count from b into a sub query something like this

```
select a.id , a.data + b.data + (select count(*) from b where b.post_id = a.id) total
from a
```

If that doesn't 'work' add sample data and expected output to the question as text.

Answer (score 0):

OK, got it:

`select id, (a.data1 + b.data2 + count(id)) as total from posts INNER JOIN comments on id = post_id group by id, a.data1, a.data2 order by total asc;`